# facebook app auto wall post, but want once per day

Tags: facebook

I developed a application in facebook, and it can be automatically to post something on the users' wall. But now I want to post only once per day, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you do call api to publish something on his/her wall, also save it into DB and then check it before each API call

```
<?php
$uid = $facebook->getUID();
$publishes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publishes WHERE uid = ".$uid." AND time > ".(time()-60*60*24);
$publish = mysql_fetch_assoc($publishes);
if (!$publish['time'])
{
    //call api and post a post to a wall
}
```